# Upgrading Visual Studio 2010 Professional to Premium, just install over?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I just discovered that our MSDN licensing covers Premium, and I installed Professional.

Can I just install Premium over Professional, or do I have to uninstall and reinstall everything? I'd rather not if installing on top of Professional is safe since I have addins and configuration already set up.

Comment: Your add-ins and config isn't that likely to survive the install anyway.  I'd avoid the risk if you don't get a "no problemo" answer.

Comment: Ok, then I'll just uninstall the 2010 things and reinstall tonight before heading for NDC tomorrow.

Comment: Actually, I took a chance and just installed on top of it. It did end up installing 3 bits only, Visual Studio 2010 Premium, one bit I don't remember the name of, and intellitrace. Don't know why it installed that last bit though as premium doesn't come with it. But everything seems to work OK, I'll keep the ISO on my drive for the time being in case it breaks down later, but looks promising so far. All the addins was present and accounted for as well.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I came across the some issue and needed to upgrade from Visual Studio 2010 Professional to Visual Studio 2010 Premium.

**I simply installed Visual Studio 2010 Premium over the Visual Studio 2010 Professional version. All worked without issue ;0)**

I did need to reinstall my VS add-ins and service packs (such as Silverlight 4 Tools) and point to my original settings file but that was all. Looks like most or all of my extensions remained in place.

Answer (score 5):

Just did this, but **used the web installer instead of the full iso**. Works like a charm. Didn't have to reinstall anything. Resharper, Silverlight and Azure templates, etc.. are working.
The only difference is that you need to insert the product key to activate it, like it says on the MSDN downloads site: "This key converts web installers and trial DVDs to the full product. It is not required for the MSDN DVD."

Hope this helps